# Prove that a number has an odd # of divisors if perfect square using bijective function

Tags: functions

A={d ∈ N : d|n ∧ d<√n} , B={d ∈ N : d|n ∧ d> √n}.
   • Find a bijective function f : A → B.

• Use the previous item to prove that n has an odd number of divisors if and only
if √n is an integer.

The bijective I found from A to B is f(x) =(n/2) * d

I'm not sure how this relates to the number of divisors however.

I know that n = f(x) * x

But where do I go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ consists of what I will call all the *lower divisors of $n$* and $B$ consists of all the *upper divisors of $n$.*

If we define our function $f: A\to B$ by $$f(a) := \frac{n}{a}$$

Then we can intuitively see that we do get a bijection.

As an example, let $n=36$

Then $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B=\{9,12,18,36\}$. (Notice we don't consider the divisor $6$ right now, as it doesn't meet the criteria to be in either $A$ or $B$) It is much clearer now to see that $f$ is indeed a bijection. See that $f(1) = 36, f(2) = 18, f(3) = 12, f(4) = 9$

Thus, we have that $|A| = |B|$, meaning that $|A|+|B| = 2|A|$ is even. The only other case we have is looking at the possible divisor equal to $\sqrt{n}$.

If $\sqrt{n}$ is not an integer, it can't be a divisor, and since all other possible divisors have been considered, then we see that $n$ has an even number of divisors.

If $\sqrt{n}$ is an integer, it clearly is a divisor of $n$. So now the number of divisors of $n$ is $|A| + |B| + 1$ which must be odd.